# ¿Como uso un textbox para una consulta de fecha?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

estoy intentando trabajar en un una consulta para buscar resultados por rango de fecha [desde - hasta], así que utilizo un textbox para que
ingresen dichos valores y se pongan en formato dd/mm/yyyy con javascript , mi problema es que cuando le doy a buscar me marca el siguiente mensaje;

> MSJ ERROR: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

BOTON

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1"  runat="server" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate2"  runat="server" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

[image: llenado de los datos utilizando el formato dd/mm/yyyy]

CONSULTA

```
 SQLTable = "SELECT  * FROM ErrorLog ";
 SQLTable += "WHERE Date between '" + txtDate1.Text + "'";
 SQLTable += " AND '" + txtDate2.Text + "'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El formato para consultar fechas en SQL Server es `yyyy-MM-dd` por tal motivo es que te da el error utilizando el formato `dd/MM/yyyy`. La solución a tu caso sería hacer esto:

```
 SQLTable = "SELECT  * FROM ErrorLog ";
 SQLTable += "WHERE Date between '" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
 SQLTable += " AND '" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate2.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
```

O en su defecto cambiar tu formato a los TextBox a `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Answer (score 3):

No me queda claro si `txtDate2` es una variable o el ID del `TextBox`; pero, debería hacer lo siguiente:

- Valide que el TextBox con ID `txtDate2` no esté vacío.
- Valide que el valor del TextBox con ID `txtDate2` sea de tipo fecha.

Ejemplo:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDate2.Text.Trim())) 
{
   DateTime fecha = DateTime.Today;

   if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDate2.Text, out fecha))
   {
       // Convertir la fecha.
       fecha = DateTime.Parse(txtDate2.Text);

       // Aplique aquí el resto de su código.
   }
   else
   {
       // El valor del campo "txtDate2" no es una fecha.
   }
}
else
{
    // El campo "txtDate2" está vacío.
}
```